Build a recursive function in NodeJS
This problem I'm trying to solve is a bit complicated. I'm trying to build a recursive function in NodeJS which would query the database to fetch results. Using the result from the database, it needs to call the function again and again.
Example, I query to DB using a parameter 001, this would result 002,003,004. 002 might breakdown further into 002-A, 002-B, 002-C, whereas 003 and 004 won't break down further. 002-A might further breakdown, 002-B might breakdown and 002-C might not.
Basically, I need to iterate through the result from the query over and over, add the result to an array and stop when no result is obtained for ANY of the previous lot numbers in the iteration.
let lotArray = [];
let resultArray = [];

async function queryDatabase(lotNumber) {
try {
    let result;
    await sql.connect(config);
    for(lot of lotNumber) {
        result = await sql.query(`SELECT mt.lot AS [MatlLot] from lot mt WHERE job_lot = '` + lot.MatlLot + `'`);
        for(res of result.recordset){
            resultArray.push(res)
        }
    }
    return resultArray;
} catch (err) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', err);
}}

queryDatabase([{MatlLot: "A2400"}])
.then(results => {
    for(res of results){
        lotArray.push(res)
    }
    console.log('Query results:', lotArray);
    queryDatabase(lotArray);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error('Error:', err);
})

So the problem I'm having is, it goes down 2 levels deep and then stops iterating. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Another problem is, when I add the condition to stop when there is no result from the DB, it stops in the middle when 003, 004 has no results, but in reality, 002 breaks down further and further.

Every time you call queryDatabase you're opening a new sql connection without ever closing the previous one, this is probably causing you to have issues. You'll want to use a connection pool to manage multiple connections for this if you're planning on having it spiderweb out recursively, and they definitely need to be closed after you're done with them

Can't you program the entire recursive selection in one database function?

@HeikoTheißen like in just one run? It needs to be recursive if it is based on the result of the previous query I guess

I think you can express that with a loop rather than a recursion.

Modern SQL databases have support for recursive queries (with recursive). Are you sure you cannot use that?

@trincot that was my first approach, however, some of these drilldowns had 10 levels deep and it took about 20 mins for SQL Server to respond back. The nodejs (api) route should be way more faster if I'm not wrong

Much depends on the actual SQL query and execution plan (does it use indexes?), but in theory this should be faster than having to submit a new SQL statement for each set of children, which must be compiled again at the server side.

I cannot comment, but thought I might provide some feedback. In the example code you provided, I see a function that returns an array and that array is pushed back to the original function. Usually when writing recursive functions, there is a logic test for determining if there is a need to continue. In this case, it seems this could be achieved with some minor changes.
async function queryDatabase(lotNumber) {
    try {
        let result;
        // This variable is only used in this function so moved it in 
        let resultArray = [];
        await sql.connect(config);
        for(lot of lotNumber) {
            result = await sql.query(`SELECT mt.lot AS [MatlLot] from lot mt WHERE job_lot = '` + lot.MatlLot + `'`);
            for(res of result.recordset){
                resultArray.push(res)
            }
        }
        // This logic determines if there were results to review and calls this function if there are.
        if (resultArray.length > 0) {
            resultArray = resultArray.concat(queryDatabase(resultArray));
            return resultArray;
        }
        // If there are no additional elements to review EG resultArray.length == 0, return an empty array.
        return [];
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error occurred:', err);
    }
}

let finalResult = queryDatabase([{MatlLot: "A2400"}])

I don't have a database to test against and cannot verify this answer, but hope it points you in the right direction.

Thanks a lot for your response. One thing I noticed is, the condition you added to check if the resultArray is not empty is coming back false. Basically before the resultArray is being populated with data, the code hits the if (resultArray.length > 0) and then condition fails. Any work around for this?

I apologize for not being able to answer this more directly, but I am not the best with async and await functions at this time.  I am surprised that the query, which has an await, does not complete prior to moving on. Since it is not actually waiting, a promise would likely be needed to resolve that.

I did want to point out that while my answer was focused around the recursive function, it does not address the hanging connection.  With a function like this, it would likely be better practice to create a connection outside of the function and pass that along so it can be closed when the function completes.

Thanks a lot for your answer. I think it works now. Appreciate it
